# MySQL conditionally populate column 3 based on DISTINCT involving 2 other columns in one table

Tags: mysql

Had a good read through similar topics but I can't quite a) find one to match my scenario, or b) understand others enough to fit / tailor / tweek to my situation.

I have a table, the important fields being;

```
+------+------+--------+--------+
| ID   | Name | Price  |Status  |
+------+------+--------+--------+
|    1 | Fred |   4.50 |        |
|    2 | Fred |   4.50 |        |
|    3 | Fred |   5.00 |        |
|    4 | John |   7.20 |        |
|    5 | John |   7.20 |        |
|    6 | John |   7.20 |        |
|    7 | Max  |   2.38 |        |
|    8 | Max  |   2.38 |        |
|    9 | Sam  |  21.00 |        |
+------+------+--------+--------+
```

ID is an auto-incrementing value as records get added throughout the day.
NAME is a Primary Key field, which can repeat 1 to 3 times in the whole table.
Each NAME will have a PRICE value, which may or may not be the same per NAME.

There is also a STATUS field that need to be populated based on the following, which is actually the part I am stuck on.

Status = 'Y' if each DISTINCT name has only one price attached to it.
Status = 'N' if each DISTINCT name has multiple prices attached to it.

Using the table above, ID's 1, 2 and 3 should be 'N', whilst 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 should be 'Y'.

I think this may well involve some form of combination of JOINs, GROUPs, and DISTINCTs but I am at a loss on how to put that into the right order for SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the count of distinct `Price` values per name, we must use a `GROUP BY` on the `Name` field, but since you also want to display all names ungrouped but with an additional `Status` field, we must first create a subselect in the `FROM` clause which groups by the name and determines whether the name has multiple price values or not.

When we `GROUP BY Name` in the subselect, `COUNT(DISTINCT price)` will count the number of ***distinct*** price values for each particular name. Without the `DISTINCT` keyword, it would simply count the number of rows where price is not null.

In conjunction with that, we use a `CASE` expression to insert `N` into the `Status` column if there is more than one distinct `Price` value for the particular name, otherwise, it will insert `Y`.

The subselect only returns one row per `Name`, so to get all names ungrouped, we join that subselect to the main table on the condition that the subselect's `Name` = the main table's `Name`:

```
SELECT
    b.ID,
    b.Name,
    b.Price,
    a.Status
FROM
    (
        SELECT Name, CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Price) > 1 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS Status
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY Name
    ) a
INNER JOIN
    tbl b ON a.Name = b.Name
```

**Edit:** In order to facilitate an update, you can incorporate this query using `JOIN`s in the `UPDATE` like so:

```
UPDATE 
    tbl a
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Name, CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT Price) > 1 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS Status
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY Name
    ) b ON a.Name = b.Name
SET 
    a.Status = b.Status
```

Assuming you have an unfilled `Status` column in your table.

Comment: Absolutely perfect as a SELECT for reporting purposes ... however, I need to run this as an update statement, and for it to update the tbl ready for interrogation by other processes.  Have had a little play but can't seem to incorporate it into an update statement myself.  Do you have some more assistance left in you?  Thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad it works for you. See my edit on how to incorporate it into an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Spot on - perfect. Thank you Zane Bien!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the status column, you could do:

```
UPDATE mytable s 
SET status = (
    SELECT IF(COUNT(DISTINCT price)=1, 'Y', 'N') c 
    FROM   (
            SELECT * 
            FROM mytable
           ) s1 
    WHERE  s1.name = s.name 
    GROUP BY name
    );
```

Technically, it should not be necessary to have this:

```
     FROM (
            SELECT * 
            FROM mytable
           ) s1
```

but there is a mysql limitation that prevents you to select from the table you're updating. By wrapping it in parenthesis, we force mysql to create a temporary table and then it suddenly is possible.

Comment: Updating using a correlated subquery could work too, but is much slower than if you were to use a JOIN which can happen over indexes. What your solution will do is execute two nested subqueries for each row in the table. If there are a lot of records, this will be quite slow. It seems the OP will perhaps want to do this update regularly or have it executed within in a stored procedure, so speed is probably an important factor. Regardless, it's always nice to have alternative solutions presented. =)

Comment: @Zane, the solution with the JOIN won't be able to use indexes either since it joins against an aggregate result from a subquery. In MySQL this will be evaluated by creating an -unindexed- temporary table. While it's true that a correlated subquery often is slower, this is not categorically true. For this particular query, if there are many distinct values for name then the subquery solution may be the better choice.